# from fixed to scrollable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanted to make a div, which is initially in a fixed position, to be scrollable after a certain div appears in the page, so I looked on the documentation of Jquery and I wrote this code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var posscroll = $(".trigger").offset();
  var pointscroll = posscroll.top - $(window).height();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= pointscroll) {
    $(".block").addClass("start-scrolling");
    console.log("point of scroll reached");
  } else {
    if ($(".block").hasClass("start-scrolling")) {
      $(".block").removeClass("start-scrolling");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  position: fixed !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.start-scrolling {
  position: absolute !important;
}

.trigger {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">some content here</div>
other content in between
<div class="trigger">scroll from here</div>
```

I also made a [simple Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/archimedo/6fn09h4a/5/)

unfortunate, I cannot make it work properly. when I reach the scrolling height my div just disappear suddenly instead of scrolling away up on the screen.

can you guys see what I'm doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: do you want the blue block to be fixed when the yellow block appears?

Comment: I want the blue block to not be anymore and follow the scroll when the yellow block appears

Comment: but your code works the way you want

Comment: If you remove all of the jQuery code the blue div remains fixed till the bottom of the page, do you want that?

Comment: the problem is that when the yellow block appears, the blue block just disappears instantly I would like it to "scroll away" instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want. But I believe that it is ...

In this case, the blue block ceases to be fixed as soon as its lower border touches the line that the yellow block touches with its upper border.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var posscroll = $(".trigger").offset();
   var pointscroll = posscroll.top-$(".block").height();
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >=pointscroll) { 
      $(".block").addClass("start-scrolling");
     //console.log("point of scroll reached");
   }else
   {
     if($(".block").hasClass( "start-scrolling")) {
       $(".block").removeClass( "start-scrolling");
     }
   }
});
```

In this case, the blue block will disappear when the top border of the yellow block touches the center line of the blue block.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var posscroll = $(".trigger").offset();
   var pointscroll = posscroll.top-($(".block").height())/2;
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >=pointscroll) { 
      $(".block").addClass("start-scrolling");
     //console.log("point of scroll reached");
   }else
   {
     if($(".block").hasClass( "start-scrolling")) {
       $(".block").removeClass( "start-scrolling");
     }
   }
});
```